# Getting mapping error message symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, one-to-many

I have 3 table :

**Events:**

- id
- typeEvents
- genreEvents
- ...

**TypeEvents:**

- id
- type
- description
- ...

**GenreEvents:**

- id
- genre
- description
- ...

So, I want to create a relation-ship between this 3 tables, but i get error mapping message in the profiler:

BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\Events

```
The mappings BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\Events#typeEvents and BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\TypeEvents#events are inconsistent with each other.
The mappings BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\Events#genreEvents and BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\GenreEvents#events are inconsistent with each other.
```

BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\TypeEvents

```
The association BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\TypeEvents#events refers to the owning side field BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\Events#typesEvents which does not exist.
```

BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\GenreEvents

```
The association BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\GenreEvents#events refers to the owning side field BISSAP\BenevolesBundle\Entity\Events#genresEvents which does not exist.
```

Events.php

```
class Events
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TypeEvents", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $typeEvents;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GenreEvents", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $genreEvents;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $user;
    [...]
```

TypeEvents.php

```
class TypeEvents
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $events
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Events", mappedBy="typesEvents", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     */
    private $events;
    [...]
```

GenreEvents.php

```
class GenreEvents
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $events
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Events", mappedBy="genresEvents", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     */
    private $events;
    [...]
```

I could see in the symfony doc => ***One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table***
but I don't want to get an another table to this simple relationship...

what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small mistake. in Events you have `private $typeEvents;`and in TypeEvents you have `mappedBy="typesEvents"` , there is a difference of 's' . Same for GenreEvents